# What does IAppbuilder.UseWebApi do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I've recently been working on an MVC site that has an api and in the startup.cs there is a line that says `app.UseWebApi`. I did some searching but I couldn't find a decent answer of what it does. Can someone please explain the concept for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It configures ASP.NET Web API to run on top of [OWIN](http://owin.org/). OWIN abstracts a web server and you can run it on top of both IIS as well as HTTP.SYS which allows you to provide a web server in your own console application. To be more specific the piece that runs on top of IIS or HTTP.SYS is [Katana](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/documentation) which is an implementation of the OWIN specification.

By calling `app.UseWebApi` you configure OWIN/Katana to send web requests through ASP.NET Web Api that in OWIN terminology is considered a middleware. This requires the NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin/).

Interestingly, ASP.NET MVC 5 cannot be configured as an OWIN/Katana middleware. it depends on `System.Web` and expects the `HttpContext` singleton to exist so it has to run on top of IIS. However, several NuGet packages that can be used in MVC projects (e.g. for authentication) is built on top of OWIN instead of taking a dependency on `HttpContext` which makes them more useful. That is one explanation of why you see OWIN used in a MVC project.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Does this single call make to "run and listen" server ?

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan: I don't think I understand your question. Calling `app.UserWebApi` does not execute the web server. It configures the web server (which may be IIS or your own host) to send HTTP request through ASP.NET Web API (which is a library). You can read an [An Overview of Project Katana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/an-overview-of-project-katana) for an overview of OWIN and Katana.

Answer (score 11):

You need to install Microsoft ASP.NET Web API2 OWIN Self Host which will resolve the issue.

You can use the following NuGet command shown below:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost
```

Comment: This answer isn't for OP's question, but it answers *my* question: What do I need to do to get the method appBuilder.UseWebApi()?